# jQuery push feed from top

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a feed site that will update itself as soon as there is a new row on the MySQL table. This is the code I have:

```
    var cacheData;
var data = $('#refresh').html();
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data !== cacheData){
                //data has changed (or it's the first call), save new cache data and update div
                cacheData = data;

                $('#refresh').fadeOut("fast");
                $('#refresh').load('index.php?_=' +Math.random()+' #refresh');
                $('#refresh').fadeIn("slow");
            }           
        }
    })
}, 1000);
```

At the moment, it just fades out completely, and then fades in with the new post. Is there a way to slide all the other results down and then fade in the new one, just like FaceBook does?
I have tried

```
    $('#refresh').animate({top:$('#refresh').height(data); - $('#refresh').height(cacheDate);},"slow");
$('#refresh').load('index.php?_=' +Math.random()+' #refresh');
$('#refresh').fadeIn("slow");
```

Is that the way to do it? I was trying to push the division down by the height of the new post, and then fade it in, but it didn't work. Can anyone spot why/what I have to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a new div element, hide it, prepend it to the parent container and use `slideDown()` for that effect. Also, only send back the new post(s) from the server (compare timestamp).